# I want to make predict function and recommendProducts function in spark ALSModel

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, als

I am studying pyspark.

ml als does not support the "predict(user,product)" function in mllib als. How can I implement the predict(user,product) function? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why u need to create custom function u have transform function that is already there for predicting

predictions = model.transform(test)